# Mongodb php compound query returns nothing

Tags: php, mongodb, php-mongodb

I have the following array:

```
Array
(
    [data.cars] => 44
    [data.xp] => Array
        (
            [$gte] => 100
            [$lte] => 500
        )

    [data.money] => Array
        (
            [$gte] => 200
            [$lte] => 1000
        )

)
```

When issuing this array to `find` it returns NULL.
Am I doing something wrong, I formated it according to this page, here:

https://www.php.net/manual/en/mongo.sqltomongo.php

So basically, if I have

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE data.cars = 44 AND data.xp >= 100 AND data.xp <= 500 AND data.money >= 200 AND data.money <= 1000
```

This query when run in the console gives exactly 4 results.

Here is the query:

```
{$and:[{"data.cars":44}, {"data.xp": {$gt:100, $lt:500}}, {"data.money": {$gt:200, $lt:1000}}]}
```

My array should work, but hey, it does not, please point me to what I'm doing wrong.

Thank you!

Comment: put your document schema in a normal way (JSON instead of php print_r)

Comment: Is the `.` actually part of the keyname or is that field a subdocument?

Comment: @Sammaye That field is a subdocument. The query works as stated in the console.

Comment: Can you show us your actual code instead of a var_dump?

Comment: @Sammaye Please tell me what will $objMongoClient->find($arrQuery); tell you. My code works well, except for this case only.

Comment: On my code I can successfully get one document back just like you can in console (though you get 4 there of course)

Comment: Ok, can you please post a PHP MongoDb driver code for querying with a compound AND query example, say three fields :) ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40961/discussion-between-gabriel-and-sammaye)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By doing `json_encode()` on two version of arrays, both at first sight seem identical, but as you will see, they are not, I discovered the "bug".

Both array's look like so:

```
array(
    'data.cars' => 44,
    'data.xp' => array(
        '$gt' => 100,
        '$lt' => 500
    ),
    'data.money' => array(
        '$gt' => 200,
        '$lt' => 1000
    )
);
```

One was hardcoded the other was dynamically built, but both json encoded were different, here they are:

```
{"data.cars":"44","data.xp":{"$gte":"100","$lte":"500"},"data.money":{"$gte":"200","$lte":"1000"}}

{"data.cars":44,"data.xp":{"$gte":100,"$lte":500},"data.money":{"$gte":200,"$lte":1000}}
```

The first array had the values as string, but couldn't see that on a regular print_r or a var_dump, so what I did was a force cast on the values and ... it **WORKED** :)

Thank you all guys for your effort and interest!

Answer (score 1):

The query on MongoDB PHP should be formatted like this:

```
array(
    'data.cars' => 44,
    'data.xp' => array(
        '$gt' => 100,
        '$lt' => 500
    ),
    'data.money' => array(
        '$gt' => 200,
        '$lt' => 1000
    )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all it is really bad to use . or $ symbols in a keys name (and I actually thought that [this is illegal](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/limits/#Restrictions%20on%20Field%20Names) ). This is because dot operator is used to access subdocuments.

So the first thing is to change that. The second thing is that you do not need $and there. So if you want to find the document, which has a = 1 and b = 2, then you do not need to do `{$and : .... }` all you need to do is `{a : 1, b : 2}`

Comment: The rules for field names are implemented third party I believe (still...) which means it is upto the driver to follow these rules, plus this is a find as such those fields will be treated as suboducments

Comment: @salvador dali This is based on the PHP driver for mongo db, please check the link provided and check out the examples, there is no $and and {a : 1, b : 2} correspondence in PHP is array('key1' => value, 'key2' => value)